# Fresh magento 2.0 showing no navigation and default data on front end and back end

Tags: magento2

I am new to magento and have fresh installed magento 2 on localserver using Xampp.

Now when I run frontend there is no navigation bar. 
And also In backend there is no deafult data in  customer, catalog, category, order,.
What I understood is default data is not displaying.

I dont know the reason. I searched on net for the solution but couldn't find any solution.

Thanks. plz help me out.

Answer (score 0):

To install sample data, enter the following command as the Magento file system owner:

```
php <magento-root>/bin/magento sampledata:deploy
```

for more information please refer this [link](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/install/sample-data-after-composer.html)